# Get Instance of controller attached to a TextField in a loop

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am trying to create a page with more than one TextField widgets in flutter. Number of textfields to display are determined at runtime. while creating those textfields a controller from the controller array is attached to each textfield. 
Everything is working as expected. but doen't matter which textfield i click, i always get the callback of all the textfields in a single onChanged function.
Therefore, i am not able to detect that value of which textfield is changed.
Please refer to code for more insight.

In-Short, i just want to know how to get the instance of textfield controller which is currently active.

Could somebody please let me know what i am doing wrong.
Thanks

```
List<TextEditingController> _controllers = <TextEditingController>[];
int controllersAttached = -1;



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  controllersAttached += 1;
for (int i = 0;i < fibProvider.quesTextList.length;i++) ...<dynamic>[
  TextField(
   autofocus: false,
   cursorColor: const Color(0xFFD8D8D8),
   maxLines: 1,
   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
   controller: _controllers[controllersAttached %fibProvider.numberOfBlanks],
   onChanged: (String data) {
     // here i can distinguish between the controllers depending upon the text 
       entered in them. but if there are 3 textfields and the same data is 
       entered in all the three then this code only returns the first 
       controller with the matched value.
     final int index = _controllers.indexWhere(TextEditingController item) {
       return data.compareTo(
         item.text.toString()) == 0;
       });
    },
 ),
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass *i* variable to *onChanged* callback inside collection-for:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final int _fields = 10;

  List<TextEditingController> controllers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controllers = List.generate(_fields, (i) => TextEditingController());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controllers.forEach((c) => c.dispose());
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title)
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            for (int i = 0; i < _fields; i++)
              TextField(
                controller: controllers[i],
                onChanged: (value) {
                  final controller = controllers[i];
                  print('Current field index is $i and new value is $value');
                },
              ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for your help....but this solution dosn't works in my case as the loop is independent of the number of textfield controllers....so it wont give correct value everytime

Comment: Where do you want to use text controller? You might pass `_controllers[controllersAttached %fibProvider.numberOfBlanks]` to _onChanged_ callback as well.

Comment: Apart from TextEdit there are several other Text widgets in a row. and a common loop to display all those in a row. Also `_controllers[controllersAttached %fibProvider.numberOfBlanks]` is not giving the correct value

Comment: I guess i figure out the way. Inside build function i added the listener to the textEdit controller from which i can easily know the textEdit controller whose value is changes

Comment: It sounds like you're attaching different controllers to text fields every time build function runs which isn't good. Yes, you can add listeners to the controllers, but the handler will be called not just on value update, but on any update like focus change etc.